# How do I keep a fancybox open after the asp:Button OnCommand event has occurred?

Tags: c#, jquery, fancybox

How do I keep a fancybox open after the asp:Button OnCommand event has occurred? I need also to communicate back to the fancybox after I've determined if there is an error or not. 
My fancybox open event:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 function CreateBox(id) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#lnk" + id).fancybox({
            autoSize: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 'auto',
            helpers: {
                overlay: { closeClick: false }
            }
        });
    });
 }
```

html event:

```
 `<a href='#ChgMemType<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>'  onclick='CreateBox(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>);' id='lnk<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>' >Change Membership</a>

        <div id='ChgMemType<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>' style="display: none; width:400px; text-align: left">
                <h3>Change Membership Type for <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FirstName")%>&nbsp;<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LastName")%></h3>
                <p>Please select the membership type below:</p>
                <input id='hfChangedMemberType' value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>" type="hidden" />

                <div id="RadioDiv">
                    <input id="rdAnnual" type="radio" onclick="SetAnnual();"  runat="server" value="Annual" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAnnualPrice" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
                    <input id="rdLife" onclick="SetLife();" runat="server" type="radio" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLifePrice" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
                </div><br />
                    <h3><div id="hiddenerror" style="color:red; display:none;">Error updating membership type for <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FirstName")%>&nbsp;<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LastName")%></div></h3><br />
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSetMemType" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.RequestID") %>' OnCommand="lbSetMemType_Command" CssClass="button" runat="server">Save</asp:LinkButton>
                </div><br />

                     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSetMemType" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.RequestID") %>' OnCommand="lbSetMemType_Command" CssClass="button" runat="server">Save</asp:LinkButton>
```

I need to toggle the display on the error message in the fancybox from my code behind or close the fancybox if no error occurs.

Comment: So you basically want to open fancybox on button click and close it in case of no errors once the response is returned from server?And what do you mean by toggle the display on error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Fancybox you are also using jQuery and then you should probably look into using `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` via jQuery instead of doing a complete postback of the entire page.

By using server controls `<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server"/>` the page automatically performs a postback to handle events on the server side. And trying to control clientside state (Fancybox content and state) via serverside code is guaranteed to get messy quickly.

If you switch to using client side controls `<button id="button1" onclick="handle_button_click()"/>` you can perform a simple post to a special asp-page which only handles updating the form data and returning an status code and a message in JSON-format or by just printing a plain string. `$.post()` has a parameter called `success` which takes a function which is called when the post response returns. From this function you can easily update the content of your Fancybox form without having to reload the entire page. Good luck :)

Another option could be to display a separate asp-page in an iframe in your Fancybox. It should work basically the same as the above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the client-side framework of ASP.NET, using at least ASP.NET AJAX: the `UpdatePanel` object enables you to selectively update only some part of your page, and using the method `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest` you can add a JavaScript client-side handler that is called at the end of every AJAX request to the server.

I this way you can surely control your client-side object visibility, based on the results of the HTTP request to your page.